# Добавление в базу postgresql sqlite3 в Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite3

У меня есть база в sqlite3 формате и мне нужно сделать так чтоб я мог добавить эту базу в postgresql но только в Django Admin я сейчас добавляю через бот телеграм

Но мне хотелось бы добавлять через сайт

Как должен он работать

В базе sqlite3 есть 1000 строк информации
А в postgresql есть 100 оба имеют одинаковые строение бд

И мне надо то что когда я отправляю файл в сайт он брал и поверх 100 postgresql добавлял 1000 sqlite3 данных и в конечном итоге чтобы было 1100 инфы у postgresql

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 и postgresql не могут иметь одинаковое строение бд, но возможно данные подойдут.

```
echo ".dump tablename --data-only" | \
  sqlite3 -ascii database.sqlite | \ 
  psql "postgresql://username:password@dbmaster:5433/databasename"
```